# How can I got Application pool Names on Drop down list in asp.net using c#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I got Application pool Names on Drop down list in asp.net using c#??

All Application names are loaded in drop down list

need ApplicationpoolNames are load in dropdownlist when Page Loading...

So I need the event Page_Load or Load_Button Click..

After loaded dropdown list, then I select Applicationpool name from Drop down List... So Now The Selected Applicationpool name only recycle...

Is it Possible Can Do???

Answer (score 0):

There is a dll in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll.
You can interact with IIS through this dll. You can get AppPool name, start, or stop, ...

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    foreach(var pool in serverManager.ApplicationPools)
    {
         //add to dropdown list
    }
}
```